# Steam will not install

Tags: software-installation, steam

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I just downloaded the latest version of steam install files.

When running install a terminal is opened and the following text is output to the terminal:

```
...............
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

then I get and error that says

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
```

I have tried all sorts of googled solutions like getting packages and updating my steam.conf file.

EDIT:
I should mention that I have not installed nvidia drivers for my gt 710. I just used the existing ones that are auto installed by Ubuntu. Could these be insufficient?

Comment: What commands did you run to install `steam`?

Comment: I downloaded the file from steampowered.com then install from ubuntu software center, then just follow all the additional steam install menu's that popped up.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install steam`. This will install `steam` from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the library before:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`
Than install Steam:
`sudo apt-get install -y steam`

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005

Comment: I did trying install a bunch of packages based on other related topics, but I didn't keep a list of what I ran. That would have my this question easier to answer I guess...

Comment: the reinstall command just resulted in the same error output as my initial post.